# using alias with type in oracle sql rising ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following code:

```
select a.DATA_ID, 
    b.FILE_NAME, b.CREATION_DATE, 
    CASE  WHEN a.cdvs_data is null THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS IS_DELETABLE from cl_dat_dst_his c inner join CL_DAT_VERSION a on c.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID=a.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID
    inner join cl_history b on c.CDVS_HIST_ID = b.CL_HIS_ID  where b.CL_HIS_TABLE_ID=14424 ORDER BY b.CREATION_DATE DESC
```

However, when i wrap the result inside the TYPE as following:

```
select uploaded_data(a.DATA_ID, 
        b.FILE_NAME, b.CREATION_DATE, 
        CASE  WHEN a.cdvs_data is null THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS IS_DELETABLE) from cl_dat_dst_his c inner join CL_DAT_VERSION a on c.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID=a.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID
        inner join cl_history b on c.CDVS_HIST_ID = b.CL_HIS_ID  where b.CL_HIS_TABLE_ID=14424 ORDER BY b.CREATION_DATE DESC
```

It is showing following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

could you give me hint what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AS IS_DELETABLE` column alias, it is invalid syntax inside the type constructor.

```sql
select uploaded_data(
         a.DATA_ID, 
         b.FILE_NAME,
         b.CREATION_DATE, 
         CASE  WHEN a.cdvs_data is null THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END -- AS IS_DELETABLE
       )
from   cl_dat_dst_his c
       inner join CL_DAT_VERSION a
       on c.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID=a.CL_DAT_VERSION_ID
       inner join cl_history b
       on c.CDVS_HIST_ID = b.CL_HIS_ID
where  b.CL_HIS_TABLE_ID=14424
ORDER BY b.CREATION_DATE DESC
```